How can I disable the "You have new mail in..." message in bash complete?
I have cron tasks logging messages to the system mail periodically. Mail check is enabled, but I don't want to see these messages when I hit TAB in the middle of typing a command.
Is there any way to customise bash complete such that mail check is disabled when it's running, or otherwise suppress its output?
Context:

GNU bash, version 5.2.26(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin23.2.0)

I've tried a few semi-naive things suggested by LLMs to override the behaviour, but always end up getting errors or it not working.
For clarity, I don't want to disable mail checking entirely, only during tab complete commands.
Example of mailcheck working OK
$ jobs
You have new mail in /var/mail/contrebis

Example of mailcheck tab annoyance
$ cd ~/expYou have new mail in /var/mail/contrebis
Experiments/

Notice how the mailcheck completion is splurged in the middle of the line where I was typing.

What is "Mail check is enabled?" I must admit I'm not sure what that means? It seems that whatever it is that you use for checking mail is causing the problem, but I don't know what that is.

Does it happen without hitting TAB sometimes?

@MarcusMüller see https://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/1/mailcheck
It's commonly enabled by default on unix/linux environments and is a useful prompt or reminder that you have unread mail.

@Fravadona yes, this is how mailcheck works. It outputs periodically when executing other commands to remind you that you have unread mail. The problem being when it pops up during a TAB execution, which is unwanted.

@contrebis thanks! I had not heard of it before! Seems quite a bit intrusive. I'll take an engineering approach: What are the time (periods) during which you want to be notified?

@MarcusMüller can be annoying, but I don't check the system messages otherwise. Generally it's fine as a top level intervention. I type in ls -al and I see the result of my command and the "You have new mail ..." message. OTOH, when I'm in the middle of typing a command (and hit tab) this visually obstructs typing a command and usually elicits swearwords.

If you want to disable bash's check for new mail messages, look in the bash man page for the MAIL, MAILCHECK, and MAILPATH shell variables.  They appear together in the man page.
It appears that one or more of these variables are set in a way to make your shell check the specified mailbox/maildir locations for new mail, and tell you at the next opportunity (usually displaying the command prompt).

So the question is how to set (or unset) this for tab completion only.

@contrebis the follow-up question then becomes: What is the party invoking mailcheck? From the man page you linked to, it seems that it needs to explicitly be invoked to do the checking; it's not a daemon sitting in the background.

I don't fully know how mailcheck works, but complete and friends devolves the completion to other processes (not sure if you would call this a "fork" or a separate shell).
E.g. completion for homebrew is devolved to a script under /opt/homebrew/completions/bash/brew
AFAIK this is when mailcheck is getting invoked.
I'd assume if you can force an environment variable on the complete process, this could disable mailcheck, but I'm not sure how one could configure this.

figuring out who invokes mailcheck is necessary to figure out how to adjust the times it gets invocated, far as I could tell. I've just run a homebrow (for Linux) container, installed mailcheck, ran zsh, but nothing there invokes mailcheck automatically, so I'm kind of clueless how to investigate!

Perhaps the variable(s) in question is being set in a shell startup script that's invoked for all shells instead of only for interactive ones?  This could cause non-interactive subshells to perform the mail check, even though their purpose is to perform command autocompletion.
